# ajax and php file upload undefined index from inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I made a php script today to upload file and also added some inputs for sending information like title and description etc. All was working just fine until i added my javascript with ajax. When i added javascript to the page and submiting the form it no longer gets the information from my input elements. Only from the fileupload input.

Here are the errors im getting:

**Notice: Undefined index: format in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\uploadvideo.php on line 15**

**Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\uploadvideo.php on line 16**

**Notice: Undefined index: desc in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\uploadvideo.php on line 17**

I do know that questions about Undefined Index have been asked probably over 1000 times here on stackoverflow but please don't mark this as a duplicate. I know that i get the error because it cannot access the values for my inputs, but why? My guess is that it has something to do with the JavaScript or it may be because i use type="button" instead of type="submit" for my submit button in the form.

So i post my code and hopefully someone here can come up with a solution.
And i tried to explain my problem as good as possible but if it's unclear in any way just let me know

**html for upload form**

```
<form action="functions/uploadvideo.php" id="upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="title">Title</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br><br>

  <label for="format">Format:</label><br>
  <select name="format" id="format">
    <option value=".mp4">mp4</option>
    <option value=".ogg">ogg</option>
    <option value=".webm">webm</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <label for="desc">Description</label><br>
  <textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea><br><br>


  Select video to upload:
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:200px;"></progress><br>
  <h3 id="status"></h3><br>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload Video" name="submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript with AJAX for a progress bar**

```
function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
  var file = _("file").files[0];
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "functions/uploadvideo.php");
  ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" butes of "+event.total;
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _("progressBar").value = 0;
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
```

**PHP File to upload file**

```
<?php
include('../config/dbconf.php');

// FFMPREG
$name = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
$nameext = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', basename($_FILES["file"]["name"])) . ".jpg";
$fullvideoname = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ffmpeg = "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
$videoFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$size = "271x170";
$getFromSecond = 5;
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size ../uploads/thumbnails/$name.jpg";

// SQL VARIABLES
$format = $_POST['format'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$date = time();

// UPLOADED VIDEO
$tmp_name= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$position= strpos($fullvideoname, ".");
$fileextension= substr($fullvideoname, $position + 1);
$fileextension= strtolower($fileextension);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (name, format, title, description, thumbnail, uploadDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $name, $format, $title, $desc, $nameext, $date);
if($stmt->execute()) {
    shell_exec($cmd);
    if (isset($fullvideoname)) {

        $path= '../uploads/videos/';

        if (empty($fullvideoname)) {
            echo "Please choose a file";
        }elseif(!empty($fullvideoname)){

            if (($fileextension !== "mp4") && ($fileextension !== "ogg") && ($fileextension !== "webm")){
                echo "The file extension must be .mp4, .ogg, or .webm in order to be uploaded";
            }elseif(($fileextension == "mp4") || ($fileextension == "ogg") || ($fileextension == "webm")){

                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$fullvideoname)) {
                    echo "Video Uploaded";
                }else{
                    echo 'Failed to move uploaded file';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "Failed";
    echo $stmt->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: what have you done to debug/fix this yourself?

Comment: if this is a js issue, I'm not your guy.

Comment: I am not really sure how i should debug this since i have no idea where the problem is

Comment: Try it without the js. If that works, then it's your js/ajax.

Comment: at best, wrap your files/post arrays inside condional isset/empty's. The call to the ajax gets made right off the bat.

Comment: Alright. Thanks i will try that and i let you know in a few minutes

Comment: sure, not a problem. You can post your own answer too; Stack lets you do that. Actually, it's even "encouraged" as do I.

Comment: Not sure how to post my own answers, Im not really spending much time here on stackoverflow. But the problem that im having seems to be related to the submit button since im using type="button". I tried to remove the javascript and wrap my variables in if statments to check if they are empty or not. but now i cannot submit the form. Nothing happens when i click the button. So my guess is that i need type="submit" but then my javascript is not working

Comment: Try a button type submit; that should work/do it, rather than an input.

Comment: i tried again with type="submit" and now the javascript worked for some reason. But it still does not get the information from my inputs. But i wrapped them in if statments as you told me and they appear to be empty. Not really sure why

Comment: And when i disable javascript it works just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
```

This creates an empty object. You need to tell it to load the contents of the form's data by doing it this way:

```
var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload_form'));
```